# Chart.js multiple charts in same page(Working but still getting error)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

Good Afternoon everyone. I'm trying to use to charts on the same page. It is working but I'm still getting an error in my console log:

```
Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '1' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'rankingsActive' can be reused.
```

My HTML

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="rankings" ></canvas>
</div>

<div>
  <canvas id="rankingsActive"></canvas>
</div>
```

My javascript code. I will post the first function that create my first chart. I have a similar function with the only difference being the last line. Different chart name and targeting my second canvas id

```js
function rankingTypes(ranks) {
  //const labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"]
  const data = {
    labels: Object.keys(ranks),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        data: Object.values(ranks),
      },
    ],
  }
  console.log(data)
  console.log(Object.values(ranks))

  const config = {
    type: "pie",
    data: data,
  }

  const rankChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("rankings"), config)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means you already made a chart on that canvas, so you must destroy that one first. This can de done like so:

```js
const c = Chart.getChart(canvasId);
if (c) c.destroy();

new Chart(canvasId, config);
```